# Падение скорости после n-ого времени работы роутера

Tags: роутер

Есть роутер `TP-Link Archer C60`.

Со временем роутер начинает резать скорость до `8-10 Mbps` из `+-95Mbps`.

Если перезагрузить/переподключиться то все налаживается на какое-то время и потом опять так.

Почему так? Роутер новый, пару дней как взяли.

Скорость тестил на `speedtest.net`. До перезагрузки и после скорости разные.

**UPD**: что через кабель, что по wifi скорость падает.

Comment: Канал попробуйте сменить

Comment: @VladSpirin канал где?

Comment: В ОС роутера... Смотрю он у вас двухдиапазонный, используйте только 5G, канал свободнее

Comment: @VladSpirin какие бывают каналы? в ОС роутера каналы вижу только у wifi.

Comment: @VladSpirin ну да вообще-то. сейчас там. Но никогда не видел "канал" для настройки подключения к провайдеру. Есть Тип подключения, логин, пароль. Я не спец в этом. Пожалуйста, не надо агриться.

Comment: У вашего роутера она по идее выглядет так: https://www.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/ArcherC60v2_Emulator/index.html

Comment: @VladSpirin я в курсе, да. где тут искать "каналы"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83640/discussion-between-vlad-spirin-and-tsyklop).

Comment: для archer C1200 помогло: режим WAN порта( к провайдеру) вместо auto выставил 100Mbps full duplex

Comment: Пришло время шить OpenWRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: для archer C1200 помогло: режим WAN порта( к провайдеру) вместо auto выставил 100Mbps full duplex]

последние несколько месяцев интернет тоже стал периодически слетать до 10 Mpbs (вместо 60), когда после замены роутера на другой (после молнии) проблемы продолжились для archer C1200 помогло: режим WAN порта( к провайдеру) вместо auto выставил 100Mbps full duplex

Comment: Поменял, скорость поднялась. Понаблюдаю несколько дней. Спасибо.

Comment: Работал-работал. Опять упала скорость до 30мбс. Что на сей раз может быть?

Comment: видимо тут другая проблема, у меня именно линк до оборудования провайдера в подъезде падал со 100 до 10 Mbps, до этого годами без проблем было , примерно с год началось

Comment: мой случай легко определяется, вставляешь провод от провайдера в ноут или ПК и смотришь какую скорость линка операционка покажет, если 10 вместо 100 то это оно.

Comment: вставлял я кабель в пк. показывает ~95 из 100. так что. даже не знаю.

Comment: спрошу навсякий , а как  скорость 30 мерял? может в это время остальные 60 качались торрентом или еще как ? :-)

Comment: Не. ПК основной выключен - ни торрентов ничего. Только супруга со смартфоном.Wifi запаролен. Показал speedtest.net.